# How to set the value of a field of type time.Time as time.Now() using reflect in Golang

Tags: go, struct, reflection

I have a struct of type

```
type test struct {
    fname string
    time time.Time
}
```

I want to set the value of the field "time" as time.Now() using reflect package only.

I am creating a function something like this one:

```
func setRequestParam(arg interface{}, param string, value interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(arg).Elem()
    f := v.FieldByName(param)
    if f.IsValid() {
        if f.CanSet() {
            if f.Kind() == reflect.String {
                f.SetString(value.(string))
                return
            } else if f.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                f.Set(reflect.ValueOf(value))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what I am trying to fix is this expression `f.Set(reflect.ValueOf(value))`, I am getting an error here.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you have? Show us a [mcve].

Comment: @icza I have updated the question

Comment: What is the context for this? Do you _have to_ use reflection?

Comment: Yes actually, I have many such structures and they have this common field time, which needs to be update, I wrote a generic function that processes all such structures, and inside that function I am setting the common field parameter's value

Comment: @ShikharTyagi I'm still not sure I understand the context, but I think using an interface common to all those struct types of yours would likely be preferable to using reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to export the struct fields, else only the declaring package has access to them.

```
type test struct {
    Fname string
    Time  time.Time
}
```

With this change your `setRequestParam()` function works.

Testing it:

```
t := test{}
setRequestParam(&t, "Fname", "foo")
setRequestParam(&t, "Time", time.Now())
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", t)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eK3gG5Rxwlv)):

```
{Fname:foo Time:2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001}
```